# VBA error 438 object doesn't support this property or method while trying to Web Scraping from a site

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm with a problem while trying to get elements from a website with VBA, I've searched this problem in StackOverflow but anyone of the answers that I tried have solved my problem.

I want to get the text that are in the element Strong, but this element are into an Div.

```
Sub StatusInvest()
Dim html As HTMLDocument
    
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
      
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://statusinvest.com.br/acoes/eua/aapl", False
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT" 'to deal with potential caching
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Set v = html.getElementsByClass("info special w-100 w-md-33 w-lg-20")(0).Value = "00000"
Set test = valor.getElementsByTagName("Strong").innerText


Range("B1").Value = teste
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This is the element that I'm trying to get:
[Sample of the HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oo79R.png)

Comment: You got the method name wrong, it should be `getElementsByClassName`. and you can provide only 1 class name. try `Set valor = html.getElementsByClassName("special")(0)` then followed by `test = valor.getElementsByTagName("strong")(0).innerText`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what was mentioned in Raymond's answer, it would be faster, and more robust, to use a single class, via css class selector, to target the desired element. The target element itself has a single class you can use. By using `querySelector` you stop matching after first match retrieved, rather than returning an entire collection and then indexing.

Use the commented out line if you want to include the currency symbol in front of the value.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub StatusInvest()
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
      
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://statusinvest.com.br/acoes/eua/aapl", False
        .SetRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT" 'to deal with potential caching
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value = html.querySelector(".value").innerText
    'ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value = html.querySelector(".icon").innerText & Chr$(32) & html.querySelector(".value").innerText

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You got the method name wrong - It should be `getElementsByClassName`.
2. `getElementsByTagName` and `getElementsByClassName` both returns a collection of element, whether there is one or more so you have to refer to index 0 when you are trying to get `strong` element.
3. `innertext` property returns a string so you shouldn't use `Set` statement but simply assign `test`.

   ```
   Sub StatusInvest()
       Dim html As HTMLDocument
       Dim valor As Object
       Dim test As String

       Set html = New HTMLDocument

       With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
           .Open "GET", "https://statusinvest.com.br/acoes/eua/aapl", False
           .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT" 'to deal with potential caching
           .send
           html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
       End With

       Application.ScreenUpdating = False        

       Set valor = html.getElementsByClassName("special")(0)
       test = valor.getElementsByTagName("Strong")(0).innerText

       Range("B1").Value = test
       Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: In addition to what @QHarr has written: `innerText` is not a method but a property. While methods perform calculations, properties only contain values. These values can be read and often also written. E.g. `responseText` can only be accessed read, not write.

Comment: @Zwenn, thanks for pointing that out! Its a typo on my part.

Comment: @Qharr, I'm certainly not aware that you can pass multiple classes, I have removed that point and thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: I guess I should clarify it is still a single class attribute but can be multi-valued i.e. have more than one class value.